# Where can I find configure script fot Qt?

Tags: mysql, qt

I want to use mysql with Qt, but I get this error:

QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLİTE QMYSQL

I found a great tutorial on the topic:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/59449/solved-with-guide-qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-build-mysql-plugin-linux-ubuntu/2

But it requires to run ./config

I can't find this script. Any suggestions? I'm on ubuntu

Comment: It's part of the source tarballs, which you can find e.g.here: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.0/single/